# Connecting to BlueTooth error

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to a Bluetooth printer in Android, the code compiles and runs OK.
But when I try to connect the the printer I get this message

> "This Device cannot be cannot be claimed for exclusive access"

Any ideas what can be done?

The Permissions I had in my app are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

I am sure it is paired and connected.

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: do you have add the runtime permissions if you are working on Marshmallow or higher?

Comment: yes all <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

Comment: Does this happen with more Bluetooth devices, or only this particular printer?